# How to access localhost remotely - Wordpress?

Tags: port-forwarding, wordpress

I have installed a LAMP stack (`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`) and wordpress (`sudo apt-get install wordpress`), but now, I would like to access my server remotely, to be used as a home fileserver.

For example, my public ip is 82.16.xxx.xxx. Opening it in firefox with the suffix :8080 brings up my router config page..?
Do I have to set up port forwarding?

BTW. Accessing via localhost/wordpress/ works fine, I would just like to access my files while away from home.

Comment: You either need to set up port forwarding, or put your machine in the "DMZ", both of which will depends on your router for specific directions. And BTW this might be off topic.

Comment: What is ''DMZ''?

Comment: Demilitarized zone, essentially it takes your computer and puts it outside your routers firewall... which can be dangerous, but less dangerous if you have a software firewall on your computer...

Comment: Well, it appears that simply going to 82.16.159.227 works, which means that port 80 is not blocked by my ISP. But now I am faced with another problem - 82.16.159.227/wordpress(/wp-admin) returns:

Comment: Neither /etc/wordpress/config-82.16.159.227.php nor /etc/wordpress/config-16.159.227.php could be found.
Ensure one of them exists, is readable by the webserver and contains the right password/username.

Comment: I have tried `cp /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php /etc/wordpress/config-82.16.159.227.php, but that doesn't work.

Comment: looks like you don't have wordpress configured correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the port of LAMP server or of your router to get rid of this conflict

To change the management port of your LAMP server check [this](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110511/lamp-stack)

Comment: Is there a way to be sure of the port my LAMP is broadcasting on?